# Java generics why doesn't this work?

Tags: java, generics

Why can I not create a map with the following generics?

```
Map<Class<K extends Item>, K> classMap;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `Map` is already generified - your job when creating a reference is to fill in the type parameter.  Unless this is inside a method parameterized with `K`, the compiler will have no idea what `K` should be replaced with (and if it were inside a parameterized method, you couldn't have `K extends Item` in the body - `K` either already extends `Item`, or it doesn't).

New type parameters can go in the signatures of classes and methods with the implicit promise that they will be filled in later.  They cannot go inside declarations.

Comment: Dang, I was worried it was something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are making an instance of `Map`, not defining it. `K` needs to be a specific class.